# The action 'RESET' with payload {"index":0,"routes":[{"name":"LogInScreen"}]} was not handled by any navigator, how to handle?

Tags: react-native, authentication, mobile, expo, asyncstorage

[image: The error]

Can I leave the error unhandled or maybe could someone advise how can I fix it. It is Expo development only warning, will it affect the app in production? We save the access token in Async Storage, after I delete it, I clean the stack and try to navigate to login page. Usually I am able to do it, but there is one condition, when I get this error: I shake my phone, I stay in the app as supposed, but when I try to log out, I get this error. This is my question, how should I handle it? Thank you

```
async function deleteValue(key) {
        try {
            await AsyncStorage.removeItem(key);
            console.log(`Value with key "${key}" deleted successfully.`);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(`Error deleting value with key "${key}": ${error}`);
        }
    }
    function checkItemExists() {
        let context = this;
        try {
            let value = AsyncStorage.getItem('access_token');
            if (value != null){
                console.log("Was deleted")
                console.log(context, "context")
            }
            else {
                // do something else
                console.log("Was not deleted")
                console.log(context, "context")
            }
        } catch (error) {
            // Error retrieving data
            console.log("Error retrieving data")
            console.log(context, "context")
        }
    };

   const onLogOutPressed =  () => {

       deleteValue('access_token').then(r => console.log(r, "rrrrrrrrrr"));
       checkItemExists();


           navigation.dispatch(
               CommonActions.reset({
                   index: 0,
                   routes: [{ name: "LogInScreen" }]
               }));

   };
```

Comment: How did you define stack navigator? Are you sure you have a stack screen named 'LogInScreen' in there?